Android Camera Permission - significant drop in the number of devices your apps supports
We have a live React Native Android application on the Play Store. In a recent update, I need to add camera permissions to the mobile app. I am using this package for image cropping: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker. After uploading the update to the Play Store, I received a warning: 'This release will cause a significant drop in the number of devices your app supports on the following form factors: Car, Chromebook, Phone, Tablet. Devices not supporting camera hardware.'
The camera functionality is not mandatory in our app, but if a device has a camera, it should work. How can I achieve this?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>"

This line added for permission

In your manifest add this
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

Indicating you dont need to have a camera to run the app
